# Using Settimeout to warn and finally redirect user for inactive session not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Idea is to give a warning to user that session is going to timeout if idle for 15 minutes and redirect to home page after 20 minutes(requirement is not to log off the user).
Currently after 15 minutes the warning comes up. I am waiting for the next five minutes, but the next alert doesn't come up. 
Please help me out in understanding on what I have written wrong here. Is the alert message to be done via use of modal?

```js
var sessionTimoutWarning = 900000; // Display warning in 15 Min.
var sessionTimout = 1200000; // Redirect in 20 minute.

var sessionsessionWarningTimer;
var sessionsessionTimeoutTimer;

// Start timers.
function StartTimers() {
  sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", sessionTimoutWarning);
  sessionTimeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", sessionTimout);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers() {
  clearTimeout(sessionWarningTimer);
  clearTimeout(sessionTimeoutTimer);
  StartTimers();
}

// Show idle timeout warning dialog.
function IdleWarning() {
  // Logout the user.
  var toContinueSession = confirm("Warning:Session is going to expire in next 5 minutes due to inactivity. Press Ok to continue. Please save the changes made.");
  if (toContinueSession) {
    ResetTimers();
  } else
    window.location.replace("../Default.aspx");
}

function IdleTimeout() {
  alert("Session has already expired. Redirecting to Home Page.");
  window.location.replace("../Default.aspx");
}
```

```html
<body style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;" onload="StartTimers();">
```

Edit: I am resetting the timer if user wants to continue by clicking Ok when the warning alert is poped up. What I am expecting is after the alert message is poped up and user is still working on something else (not coming on this page), after 5 minutes the second popup should come up stating that session is already expired i.e. IdleTimeout() getting called, which is not happening.

Comment: I made you a snippet and got `sessionTimoutWarning ` not existing - also don't use alert when you want to continue a timer

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Comment: I'm presuming that `sessionsessionTimoutWarning` (double `session`) is actually a typo whilst pasting into SO?  Otherwise, the 15 minute timer could never have worked...

Comment: Yes, essionsessionTimoutWarning was updated wrongly when trying to copy... updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling `ResetTimers();` in `IdleWarning()`, and this is cancelling the `sessionTimeoutTimer`.

Look at the code:

```
...
if (toContinueSession) {
    ResetTimers();
} ...
```

And:

```
// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers() {
  clearTimeout(sessionWarningTimer);
  clearTimeout(sessionTimeoutTimer);
  StartTimers();
}
```

You restart the 20 minute timer if the user clicks `OK` on the alert.  If they do not click `OK` then they are immediately redirected, so your timeout code can never execute.

I'm presuming that even if the user clicks `OK` you do *not* want to restart the `sessionTimeoutTimer`, as that should still trigger after the 20 minute deadline.

**Edit following OP comment**

I now understand that you are concerned that the `sessionTimeoutTimer` does not execute if the user has not noticed the alert popup.

Unfortunately, browser dialogs are modal and they freeze underlying timers: **your `sessionTimeoutTimer` will not execute if an `alert` or `confirm` popup is open**.

There is no way to override this behaviour using the standard `alert` or `confirm` popup - it is built in to the browser and cannot be changed.

As an alternative, you could implement your own popup dialog instead of using `alert`, which will therefore *not* block the timer from running.  I cannot think of an alternative way of resolving this issue.

Comment: What I am looking for is user doesn't click on anything i.e. user is working on some other thing and hasn't noticed the alert. So the message/alert box is still open. So after next 5 minutes the IdleTimeout() should get called and popup the Session expired message. and now when user comes and clicks user is redirected.

Comment: @SoumyaMandal Please see my updated answer. TL;DR: Timers and intervals **do not function** when a browser dialog window is open.

Comment: That's what I thought is happening and had mentioned in my question as well if I have to create my own modal and use that. Will try and check that out. Thanks!!.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a type for the variable `sessionTimoutWarning` since you actually declare it as `sessionsessionTimoutWarning` but use it as `sessionTimoutWarning` (one session). You should also use the actual function objects rather than surround them in strings when calling timeouts. i.e.

```
setTimeout(IdleWarning, sessionTimoutWarning);
```

compared to

```
setTimeout("IdleWarning()", sessionTimoutWarning);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sessionsessionTimoutWarning = 900000; // Without "var" - make global
sessionTimout = 1200000;  // Without "var"  - make global
```

OR Method #2:

```
window.sessionsessionTimoutWarning = 900000; // Without "var" - make global
window.sessionTimout = 1200000;  // Without "var"  - make global
```

usage:

```
//..
console.log(window.sessionTimout); // make sure is available
```

Then replace alert with console.log 
ex.

```
console.log("Session has already expired. Redirecting to Home Page.");
```

Debug with console log if everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I have modified some part

```
 var sessionTimoutWarning = 900000; // Display warning in 15 Min.
    var sessionTimout = 1200000; // Redirect in 20 minute.  //change this to 5 min 

    var sessionsessionWarningTimer;
    var sessionsessionTimeoutTimer;

    // Start timers.
    function StartTimers() {
      sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", sessionTimoutWarning);

    }
    function EndSession()   //this will end the complete session 
    {
          sessionTimeoutTimer = setTimeout(IdleTimeout(){
              window.location.replace("../Default.aspx");

          }, sessionTimout);
          //redirect to the page in this function 
    }

    // Reset timers.
    function ResetTimers() {
      clearTimeout(sessionWarningTimer);
     // clearTimeout(sessionTimeoutTimer);
      StartTimers();
    }

    // Show idle timeout warning dialog.
    function IdleWarning() {
      // Logout the user.
      var toContinueSession = confirm("Warning:Session is going to expire in next 5 minutes due to inactivity. Press Ok to continue. Please save the changes made.");
      if (toContinueSession) {
          //here you get the event after the 15 min  .
        ResetTimers();
      } else
      {
          // if he didn't continue then, call the session clear function
          EndSession() //but in this changes have tge timer is 5 min because already 15 is completed .

      }
    }

    function IdleTimeout() {
      alert("Session has already expired. Redirecting to Home Page.");

    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <body style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;" onload="StartTimers();">

<!-- end snippet -->
```